# Display records serially according to the id registered in database in HTML table using php

Tags: php, html, database, odbc

I want to display all the data registered in my database serially according to their id such as(1,2,3,4....50,51,52) in html table in a .php page. But when I run the .php page it display disordered ID numbers according to submit sequence. Such as if I submit ID-10 first, then ID-15, then id-9 it should be shown as(9,10,15) but it's showing as (9,15,10). How to fix this please help ? code sample below-

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQzKj.png) 
   '

```
   <tr>
      <th>ID </th>
      <th>Customer Name </th>
      <th>Email</th>
   </tr>

  <tr>
  <?php 
     $conn=odbc_connect('formdsn','','');
     if (!$conn)
       {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer"; 
     $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

     while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
        echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["Email"].'</td>
        </tr>';
     }
  ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

'

Comment: use order by tag in your sql query SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY ID ASC

Comment: @Sachin can you please make an answer with your comment?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
```

with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY ID ASC";
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply by adding `ORDER BY ID`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY `ID`";
```

If you want to sort by latest updated record first then make sure you are having any field like `updated_date` field in your `Customer` table and you need to insert updated `datetime` in this field whenever you `update` record (first time on `insert`) and then when fetching record from `Customer` table you can add order by `updated_date DESC` to get latest updated record first.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY `updated_date`";
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: yeah it gives a extra knowledge